# Eloquent & Carbon Time Difference

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a basic table which captures time and attendance.

I'm trying to out put the total hours on site, from my eloquent query:

```
$attendance = DB::table('staff_attendances')
        ->whereBetween('in_date', array($date1, $date2))->where('staff_id', $ID)->select('first_name', 'last_name', 'in_date', 'out_date', 'in_time', 'out_time')->get();
```

I get the following back in json.

```
[{"first_name":"TestFirst","last_name":"TestLast","in_date":"2016-01-30","out_date":"2016-01-30","in_time":"11:40:34","out_time":"12:41:10"},

{"first_name":"TestFirst","last_name":"TestLast","in_date":"2016-01-30","out_date":"2016-01-30","in_time":"13:02:27","out_time":"14:02:32"}]
```

Which method would be best to out put total hours on site?

I've tried using carbon with the following:

```
$startTime = Carbon::parse($attendance->in_time);
$finishTime = Carbon::parse($attendance->out_time);
$totalDuration = $finishTime->diffInHours($startTime);
```

But I get "Trying to get property of non-object"

Answer (score 2):

Carbon is a class which extends DateTime class. It should deal with date and/or time. But it looks like your parse call don't return a Carbon instance. So I advise you to use a full date format ("Y-m-d H:i:s") as in the following example :

```
<?php 
    $totalDuration = 0;
    foreach($attendance as $aAttendance){
        $startTime = Carbon::parse($aAttendance->in_date.' '.$aAttendance->in_time);
        $finishTime = Carbon::parse($aAttendance->out_date.' '.$aAttendance->out_time);
        $totalDuration += intval($finishTime->diffInHours($startTime));
    }
?>
```

With the foreach instruction you will go through all the attendances and do the sum of all diffInHours returns in the variable $totalDuration.

Comment: Will this work with more than one row in the response? I'm trying to get the total number of hours for all rows.. ? Thanks

Comment: @YvonnickFRIN Your answer is good, but the first statement of your answer is broad and inaccurate and can be misleading to future readers, so please revise it. Carbon extends the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.datetime.php) class which, as the name suggests, works with both date and time, and can work with each of them individually, so it can very well parse time without a date.